# The right way to verify email in Meteor

Tags: email, meteor

I am trying the email verification function of Meteor, following [Meteor #20: Verify an Email with Meteor Accounts](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-20-verify-an-email-with-meteor-accounts/42).

I have some questions about step 3 and 4:

1. In Step 3, `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id);` doesn't work, while `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id, user.emails[0].address);`works. Why I need specify email address explicitly?
2. In Step 4, should I modify "Homepage" in `Template.Homepage.created = ...` to my homepage template name?
3. In the doc of Meteor 1.0.4, I can't find a attribute named "created" under "Template.myTemplate".
   So if `Template.Homepage.created = ...` has been deprecated?
   Is it right to written as `Template.<myhomeTemplateName>.onCreated = ...`?
4. Is this the best solution to verify email?

Comment: for step-1, did you provided MAIL_URL environment variable ?

Comment: @ajduke yes, I've added it with `process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://...` in Meteor.startup function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_sendverificationemail), if the email is not specified, the email must be in `emails` for the user and must be unverified. If you've already verified the address, no email will be sent unless the address is explicitly specified.

   > **email** String
   >   Optional. 
   >   Which address of the user's to send the email to. This address must be in the user's emails list. Defaults to the first unverified email in the list.
2. Yes
3. From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onCreated), it appears onCreated should be called like this:
   `Template.HomePage.onCreated(function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

For Meteor 1.0.5, use

```
Template.<yourTemplate>.onCreated(function() { ... })
```

instead of

```
Template.<yourTemplate>.created = ...
```

in step 4 of [Meteor #20: Verify an Email with Meteor Accounts](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-20-verify-an-email-with-meteor-accounts/42).

The demo below works fine under Meteor 1.0.5.

verifyEmail.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Verify Email</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sending Email Demo</h1>
  {{> loginButtons}}
</body>
```

verifyEmail.js: (replace user, password and server value for your case)

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.SendAnyEmail.onCreated(function() {
    if (Accounts._verifyEmailToken) {
      Accounts.verifyEmail(Accounts._verifyEmailToken, function(err) {
        if (err != null) {
          if (err.message = 'Verify email link expired [403]') {
            console.log('Sorry this verification link has expired.')
          }
        } else {
          console.log('Thank you! Your email address has been confirmed.')
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    smtp = {
      username: 'user@example.com',
      password: 'password',
      server: 'mail.example.com',
      port: 465
    };

    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;

    Accounts.emailTemplates = {
      from: 'Administrator <user@example.com>',
      siteName: 'YourSite',
      verifyEmail: {
        subject: function(user) {
          return 'Verification email from Example.com';
        },
        text: function(user, url) {
          return 'Hi,\n' +
            'Please open the link below to verify your account on Example.com:\n' + url;
        }
      }
    };
  });

  Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
      Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id);
    }, 2 * 1000);
    return user;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `server/main.js`, simply set anywhere outside the `Meteor.startup` block.

```
Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: true
});
```